# performance issues with linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, stan, rstan

I am fitting a linear mixed model

$y_{t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1t} + \beta_2x_{2t}+ \beta_{0i[t]} + \beta_{1i[t]}x_{1t} + \beta_{2i[t]}x_{2t} + \beta_{0j[t]} + \epsilon_t$

with `stan_lmer` using

```
prior_fit_1 <- normal(location = c(2.0, 0.0, 0.0), scale = c(4.0, 9.0, 9.0))
fit_1 <- stan_lmer(response ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor3
                              (1 + predictor1 + predictor2 | group1) 
                              (1 | group2),
                              data = dat, refresh = -1,
                              prior = prior_fit_1, chains = 3, cores = 3, iter=500)
```

where the dataset `dat` has >750k observations. I made sure that the predictors and the response are roughly on the same scale (by comparing their min and max values). Here is a summary of the dataset

```
         response   predictor1  predictor2  predictor3
count   773737      773737      773737      773737
mean    7.645656    4.766701    1.383317    4.147674
std     2.598273    4.388669    3.136783    2.274438
min    -3.688879    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
25%     5.991465    0.000000    0.000000    2.639057
50%     7.681076    5.799093    0.000000    4.143135
75%     9.383201    8.476134    0.000000    5.673323
max    21.416413    20.706678   24.214083   8.942984
```

It tells me

```
Gradient evaluation took 3.71 seconds
1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 37100 seconds.
Adjust your expectations accordingly!

Gradient evaluation took 3.66 seconds
1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 36600 seconds.
Adjust your expectations accordingly!

Gradient evaluation took 4.06 seconds
1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 40600 seconds.
Adjust your expectations accordingly!
```

so in the worst case it would take ~12 hours to complete 1000 iterations in a chain. The model has been running for 12 hours now and I am a bit surprised that it hasn't finished yet because I run only 500 iterations per chain.

Any suggestions as to why that is and how I can speed it up?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dataset has >750k observations, then that's probably just how long you'll have to wait for it. One of my colleagues had a dataset with over a million observations, and his models routinely took that long to run. Possible improvements might be:

1) Get coefficients from an `lmer` model first, and use those coefficients as starting points for the `stan_lmer` model.

2) Assign tighter priors, as this might help to speed up the warmup. With 750k estimates, the data will likely swamp the priors anyway.

3) Get access to a machine with more cores, and run more chains for a shorter period of time (assuming warmup period is long enough).